# SQL Server Ignoring IF Statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Every night, I backup my production server and push the backup to my dev server. My dev server then has a job that runs which first checks if the backup file exits, if so check if the database exists in dev and if so drop the database, then restore from file. This all works fine, unless the file is not yet complete due to slow transfer, etc. If the file is not completely downloaded when the job runs then the first step sees it exists and drops the database. The next step tries to restore and of course fails. The next day when the job runs I would expect that when it checks if the database exists, it would see that it does not and shouldn't attempt to drop it and just restore. However, what's happening is the job is unable to drop the database and just fails at that point. This requires manual intervention to get the database restored, which is my problem. I'm less concerned with the fact of having no database existing on the server for a day (in theory) as I can tweak the schedule further to restore sooner. What I am concerned with is why is the IF statement not working to check if the database exists and attempts to drop a database regardless? Here's the T-SQL code that I am using:

```
DECLARE @output INT
DECLARE @SqlPath varchar(500) = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\PROD-01_prod_backup.bak'

EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_fileexist @SqlPath, @output OUT
IF @output = 1
BEGIN
    IF (EXISTS (SELECT name FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases WHERE ('[' + name + ']' = '[PROD-01]')))
    BEGIN
        ALTER DATABASE [PROD-01] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
        DROP DATABASE [PROD-01]
    END

    RESTORE DATABASE [PROD-01] FROM DISK = @SqlPath
END
```

Comment: Have you checked the `status` of the database to see if it is in a Heisenberg state like _loading_ or _recovering_ that is between existing and not?

Comment: also, this is why you should use try catch, and i'd just use restore over the database, no need to drop it, so that if it fails it's rolled back.

Comment: @HABO Yes I have checked manually and it shows that it doesn't exists, not stuck in any other state.

Comment: @scsimon I originally had done that, but there are some additional steps that I add which I didn't include in my T-SQL above such as dropping columns from a table and restoring some rights. If I don't drop the table first and the restore fails then dropping the columns fails the job or the additional user rights are orphaned.

Comment: orphaned logons can certainly happen when restoring on a different server... but only providing partial code makes it hard to troubleshoot completely. What's the exact error message you are getting?

Comment: @scsimon I left off the additional code as my question is why is my IF statement being ignored and the proc attempting to drop the database regardless if it exists or not. The rest of the code works without issue when the job doesn't fail attempting to drop a database that doesn't exist. I can't see the exact error messages currently as I had to restore a new database manually a few minutes ago for an emergency issue to push something to prod. I can look and post it here though upon the next failure.

Comment: @scsimon I will be adding a try... catch statement though. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: if you can't see the error message, then how do you know the if statement is being ignored? I'd expect to see an error message "can not drop database ____ because it does not exists" but if you aren't seeing this, then how are you sure that part of the batch is actually executed? How do you know it fails on that point without any error messages?

Comment: I tried this right now and it works fine for me. Try adding a print statement to be sure the if block gets really executed. (Why are you not just using " WHERE name = 'PROD-01', you don't need the brackets here.)

Comment: The error log isn’t lost because of a restore. That’s at the server level.

Comment: @scsimon You are correct, my mistake. I just pulled the error from the log file and it is.. "failed with the following error: "Database 'PROD-01' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly."

Comment: Based on that, it’s not trying to drop it there. It’s somewhere else in your code.

Comment: @scsimon Just to clarify I believe the error is actually in the ALTER DATABASE command just before it actually attempts to drop the database. This command should not be run though as it's part of the IF statement I originally mentioned in my question above.

Comment: I don't see how... http://rextester.com/NNB22298

Comment: @scsimon I added try... catch blocks and everything is working now as expected. When the database is not present it goes to the catch block now which is in essence a  Do Nothing block. and in either case processing continues after that. If you want to put that suggestion as an answer here I'd be happy to accept it as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how this is happening, as I am unable to reproduce, but a `TRY / CATCH` block is an ideal solution for this case:

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON
GO


DECLARE @output INT
DECLARE @SqlPath varchar(500) = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\PROD-01_prod_backup.bak'

EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_fileexist @SqlPath, @output OUT
IF @output = 1
BEGIN
    IF (EXISTS (SELECT name FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases WHERE (name = 'PROD-01')))
    BEGIN TRY
        ALTER DATABASE [PROD-01] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
        DROP DATABASE [PROD-01]
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE();
    END CATCH

    RESTORE DATABASE [PROD-01] FROM DISK = @SqlPath
END
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you very much!